# Why you can check if array exists in Javascript with .length

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

As I Java programmer I do not understand why you can check if the array is empty using `if(array.length)`. Can someone please elaborate?

Comment: Take a look at the concepts of [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values in JavaScript.

Comment: The title and the actual question are completely different. The question itself is also ambiguous, because Java arrays have a `length` property as well. If your question is "why can `array.length` be used as boolean expression" then it has nothing to do with arrays. You may want to clarify what you actually like to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `array.length` is evaluated as `true` when it has at least one element. When array is empty `array.length` returns `0` which is evaluated as `false`.

So the bottom line is you can use `if (array.length)` to check if array is NOT empty.

Answer (score 3):

because first if `array` is not defined (undefined) then you can't get the length property of an undefined object.

just use `if (typeof array !== 'undefined')` will give the result if array exsit.

as you can see in the example code:

```
zero.length --> 0
!zero.length --> true
!!zero.length --> false
```

`0` is considered as false in `if(0)` or `!!0`/`!0`, since an empty array have length of 0, it is considered as false, **in that case you can't use it to determine if this array exsit or it is just empty**.

```js
var array = [];

if (typeof array !== 'undefined'){
  console.log('array exsit: true');
} else {
  console.log('array exsit: false');
}

var zero = [];
console.log('zero.length --> '+zero.length);
console.log('!zero.length --> '+!zero.length);
console.log('!!zero.length --> '+!!zero.length);


if (typeof array2 !== 'undefined'){
  console.log('array2 exsit: true');
} else {
  console.log('array2 exsit: false');
}
```

#### below is the table for js `truthy` and `falsy`

```js
function checkTruthiness(raw, exp) {
  row = $('<tr />').appendTo('#output');
  
  if ( exp ) {
    row.append('<td class="truthy">' + raw + '</td>');
  } else {
    row.append('<td class="falsy">' + raw + '</td>');
  }
    
  if ( !exp ) {
    row.append('<td class="truthy"> !' + raw + '</td>');
  } else {
    row.append('<td class="falsy"> !' + raw + '</td>');
  }   
    
  if ( exp == true ) {
    row.append('<td class="truthy">' + raw + ' == true </td>');
  } else {
    row.append('<td class="falsy">' + raw + ' == true </td>');
  }
    
  if ( exp == false ) {
    row.append('<td class="truthy">' + raw + ' == false </td>');
  } else {
    row.append('<td class="falsy">' + raw + ' == false </td>');
  }  
    
  if ( exp === true ) {
    row.append('<td class="truthy">' + raw + ' === true </td>');
  } else {
    row.append('<td class="falsy">' + raw + ' === true </td>');
  }
    
  if ( exp === false ) {
    row.append('<td class="truthy">' + raw + ' === false </td>');
  } else {
    row.append('<td class="falsy">' + raw + ' === false </td>');
  }
    
  if ( Boolean(exp) ) {
    row.append('<td class="truthy">Boolean(' + raw + ')</td>');
  } else {
    row.append('<td class="falsy">Boolean(' + raw + ')</td>');
  }
}

checkTruthiness('0', 0);
checkTruthiness('NaN', NaN);
checkTruthiness('""', "");
checkTruthiness('false', false);
checkTruthiness('null', null);
checkTruthiness('undefined', undefined);
checkTruthiness('{}', {});
checkTruthiness('[]', []);
checkTruthiness('"0"', "0");
checkTruthiness('"false"', "false");
```

```css
td {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:5px 10px;   
}
.truthy {
    background-color:#cfc;
}
.falsy {
    background-color:#fcc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="output"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`array.length` will return 0 if the array is empty, `0` is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value.

**Falsy values**

> Examples of falsy values in JavaScript (which translate to false and
>   thus bypass the if block):

- `false`
- `0` (zero)
- `""` (empty string)
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`

So

```
var arr = [];

arr.length === 0
arr.length == false
!arr.length === true
```

Any non-zero number is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, and will enter the if block.

Answer (score 0):

Zero coerces to `false`:

```js
if (!0) console.log(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically calculate the number of elements in the array through the **lenght** property (the same property can also be applied to a string to count its characters, in the case of the Array () the number of indexes is calculated). Since .lenght returns the number of array elements, if it is empty you will have 0 as the return value.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the programming languages, `0` and `null` (`undefined` in case of JavaScript) are equivalent to `false`. And thus that `if` condition is correct.

Unless you want totally different behavior for `0` and `null`, then you'll have to do check using `==` (`===` in case of JS). This statement returns boolean value.

JavaScript considers `NaN` & Empty string also as false.